# How do you make photoresist/photohardening paint?

Tags: photochemistry

I have been looking into making my own PCB's, but I noticed there is little information on making photo hardening paint. This is a critical component when etching the circuit, and I am very curious on the chemistry involved in making it. I understand there are better methods to make your own pcb, but I am curious how photoresist is made

Comment: Did you consider to print the circuit on glossy magazine paper with a laser printer and transfer the mask with a flat iron instead?

Comment: yes, but I'm not looking for the easiest method, I'm curious on the photoresist method.